# Camel File2 component with recursive option. How to remove empty directory

Tags: apache-camel

When I set `recursive=true&delete=true` for Camel File2 component it looks into subdirectories. However, then file is processed it gets removed, but directory still exists. How to automatically remove such directory? Isn't there any options for this. If now - probably this should be added to the wish-list into Camel issue tracking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The file component can only delete the file, not any directory. You will have to delete the directory yourself.