# How to remove an empty directory in Camel?

Tags: java, directory, apache-camel

I have seen that there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916397/camel-file2-component-with-recursive-option-how-to-remove-empty-directory) but I cannot comment on this to ask my question as I don't have enough reputation.

I have the same issue where an empty directory is left over after files have been removed from within it. I currently have a bean to check the directory and remove this if empty.

```
from("file://"+inputLocation+"?initialDelay=5000&delay=2000&recursive=true&delete=true")
        .process(databaseProcessor())
.recipientList(simple("file://"+location+"/${in.header."+AppConstants.DIRECTORYLOCATION+"}"))
.to("bean:folderCheck?method=deleteEmptyDirectories()");
```

The **bean:folderCheck** has a method that will delete the directory if empty. I understand that the delete on the *from* section of the route will happen after the route has completed, thus branding the **bean:folderCheck** useless at present. I want to find a way to run this at a time when the directory is empty.

Is there a way to call this bean, either within this route or another, rather than periodically polling to see if the directory is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use on completion to do some work after the route is done.

- http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html

Then you can call the bean from there. Just mind the on completion runs in parallel (using another thread).

And mind that from Camel 2.14 onwards on completion runs by default not in parallel mode, but you can easily turn that on again.